# How to make a connection between a unity3d webplayer and an external application?

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine, cross-domain

I am working on a web-based simulation environment which can be controlled via the network. I have an application written in python, which sends string commands to webplayer. However, none of the examples that I tried so far made this happen. In some of them I got a crash (when I used Zero-MQ library on both sides) or the others I got "no valid crossdomain policy found" error.

I don't have to much experiment with unity3d and especially with networking. I put the crossdomain file in both webplayer and application root folder, but still not working.

1. Do I miss some code to search for the crossdomain file?
2. Should I need to use some build-in networking code?

I really appreciate it, if you could share your ideas or experiment about this particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

Application that sends commands to web player. So are you using Unity as the server?

I think a common approach would be to have Unity connected to your application as a client, you would use the WWW class to connect to a server that hosts your application, as described [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/SecuritySandbox.html).

Maybe you'd need to make the application send commands to Unity instead of making Unity pool for commands, so in this case you should probably use a network platform that is known to work well with Unity, like [Photon](https://www.exitgames.com/en/Realtime).